# How to pull columns with '1' in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering if there was an easy way to do this:

I have a user_id column and then 33 other columns with either a '0' or a '1' as the type. How can I easily select all of the columns where the user_id = 320 and the column's data equals 1?

The column titles are labeled 1-33. In the end I want to join it to another table where 1-33 is the id to a label column.

Does this make sense?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: When you say "columns with either a '0' or a '1' as the type", do you mean the values of those 33 other columns could be either 0 or 1? What do you mean by "type"?

Comment: Bit masking > 33 columns with either 0 or 1 as value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this I get all the fields and test if it BIT and then inject it to the query 
And please tell me the result

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM sometable");
if (!$result){
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
    $str =""; 
    $nums = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $i = 0 ;  
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
       $i++; 
       if($row['Type'] = 'BIT' && $i != $nums){
           $str .= " WHERE `".$row['Field']."` = 1 AND";  
       }
       elseif($row['Type'] = 'BIT' && $i == $nums){
           $str .= " WHERE `".$row['Field']."` = 1 "; 
       }
    }
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM mytable user_id = 320 AND ".$str;
$q = mysql_query($query);
```

This is for the first part of you question 
the second part the same operation 
and this working without knowing the fields name

Comment: @AlexLunix that is, unfortunately, valid PHP. Mostly used for HTML templating, and not usually for regular scripts. http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php Often seen in the code of Visual Basic refugees and Ruby wannabes.

Comment: Wow, I've never actually seen this before, thanks for the link.

Comment: @Michael can you please tell me why I should use it only with HTML templating coz I heard that couple of times and still don't know why 

I see this type of syntax more readable and easier to debug

Comment: @UserB You can use it for whatever purpose suits you, but it just isn't common practice to use in regular code. It was specifically designed for HTML templating, so as to avoid having to do things like `<?php { ?>` to close control structure blocks. It makes it easier to do things like `<?php if ($condition): ?> <html /> <?php endif;?>`

Comment: @UserB If you keep consistent indentation, it's ok, but if not, it becomes very unreadable.  You'll just about never see this syntax in major PHP applications, except for in the view templates.

Comment: Hey @UserB thanks for the response! It doesn't appear to be doing it correctly. My table setup is (SORRY IT DOESN'T KEEP FORMATTING):

TABLE: USERCATS
     -USERID (320)
     -1
     -2
     -...
     -33 
TABLE: CATS
     -CATID (1, 2, 3, ..., 33 from the column names from the USERCATS table)
     -CATNAME - So a real name for the category such as 1 = Cats, 2 = Dogs, 3=Pigs, etc...

I want to get get the CATNAME from the CATS table where a user has shown interest (the 1-33 column number would be '1' if they don't like it, it would be '0')... does this make sense?

Comment: Also the USERCATS table - the USERID is int(11) and the 1-33 column is a tinyint(1)... not BIT which was seen in the previous code.

Comment: about your condition not the bit columns write them down where $query is and the BIT will be generated